# Long usb serial connection jobs stop at the 8 hour mark. I suspect timeout or maximum-resource-used issue

Tags: usb

Using Ubuntu 14.04 lts 32 bit Dell laptop, CURA software and lulzbot mini 3d printer

**Connected via serial usb**

Long print jobs stop at the 8 hour mark. I suspect it is a timeout issue or perhaps a maximum-resource-used type of problem. I'm in the group dialout in order to gain permission to read/write serial usb devices, if that helps.

Ubuntu noob - please be nice.

There is no file at /etc/timeouts.

**what,how,where** things can I check (logs I'm guessing) to isolate the cause of this phenomena?

I was thinking of creating the /etc/timeouts file and adding the line:
Al:*:*:*

which I think would remove all timeouts for everyone regardless of group, username or tty

Single user/use machine so I have plenty of latitude to make that sort of a change without impacting others.

Seems like a rather big hammer, I know.

Comment: Why would you think that creating a file called `/etc/timeouts` would have any effect on anything?

Comment: Please see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/timeouts.5.html

Answer (score 0):

Most of your system's log files are kept in `/var/log/` (or a subdirectory of `/var/log`) and can be viewed with `Applications` `->` `System Tools` `->` `KSystem Log`.

Or, if you are comfortable with the command line:

```
# Assume printer failed at `18:54:35` 

sudo zegrep '[[:space:]]18:5[0-4]:' /var/log/* /var/log/cups/*
```

to see all the log entries from `18:50:00` to `18:54:59`, which probably includes whetever is killing the print job.

With different regexps (see `man grep` and everything in `See Also`) you can extract different time ranges. Once you narrow in on which events you want to care about (or ignore), more complex regular expressions can do more.

Of course, before you do any of these commands, read `man sudo`, `man zegrep` and `man grep` until you understand what I'm asking you to do, and how harmful it is.